# How can I finish an attic floor where the recessed lighting protrudes above the joists?

Tags: attic

I’m trying to finish an attic, however, can lights from the living room and other electrical peeks above the joist about an inch give or take.  How would I finish the floor with those obstructions in the way.  By the way the joist are 16 inches on center.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How large are your attic joists? Sometimes the joists are sized to be an attic, not a finished space.

Comment: The clearance needed would depend on the type of can light. Some need 3" above to allow the heat to dissipate.

Comment: Thx for the answers, the joist I think are 2x6, and I’m just guessing.  So in this case if it’s not sufficient enough for a floor what do I need to do, and what if subfloor is placed over existing, what would or could happen.

Comment: How far do the 2x6s span? @TajuanRiley

Comment: 16 inch’s is what they span

Comment: 16" is the gap between the joists - what is *length* of the joists.  If it's anything over a few feet, that sounds like they are sized for holding up a ceiling, not providing a stable floor to an attic room.

Comment: Voting to close. Questions remain and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 2):

If the existing joists are adequate to support an attic floor, it will be far easier to replace the recessed can lights with wafer style LED lights such as these from Lithonia.

[image: Lithonia LED wafer lights]

When shopping, check carefully to see that the lights you select will work out with the openings in your ceiling.  You might want to bring one of the trims from your existing lights with you to the store.

If the joists are too small and need to be beefed up, you can sister new, larger joists to the existing joists, but that will probably be a lot of work.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the new fittings can be closed in - some LED units cannot be covered and need to breathe.  Check the paperwork!